# Join Vec<String> into String after prepending each value

Tags: rust

If given a `Vec<String>` of values, how can I get back a `String` where each has been prepended with `-a` . Here is my solution, and it works, but it feels obtuse, so I'd like to know the best way to do this.

- input: `["foo", "bar"]`
- output: `-a foo -a bar`

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5558637f3462414cd57926db0faaf20b

```
fn f(args: Vec<String>) -> String { 
    args.into_iter()
    .map(|s| format!("-a {}", s))
    .collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" ")
}

fn main() {
    let args = ["foo", "bar"].iter().map(|&s| s.into()).collect();
    println!("{}", f(args));
}
```

Comment: Side note: if the goal is to print a data structure you may prefer to implement `fmt::Debug` or `fmt::Display`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's concise but there are two points of inefficiency here:

- creating a new vec instead of modifying the vec in place
- creating a lot of strings when you just want one string

A first improvement would be to just prepend to the strings in place but if you want something more direct you could do

```rust
fn f(args: Vec<String>) -> String {
    let mut s = String::new();
    for arg in args {
        if !s.is_empty() {
            s.push(' ');
        }
        s.push_str("-a ");
        s.push_str(&arg);
    }
    s
}
```

If performance is irrelevant for your use case, then there's no problem with your code. Without additional crates `join` does need a vec today (you could use [intersperse](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.intersperse) but only in nightly).

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept a slight loss of speed - here is a shorter solution using `fold`:

```
fn f(args: Vec<String>) -> String { 
    args.iter()
    .fold(String::new(), |s1, s2| s1 + " -a " + s2)
    .trim_start().to_string()
}
```